# Hermitian matrix is always positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $\sum$ be the covariance matrix. I know that this matrix is $n\times n$, symmetric and positive definite. To decompose it with Cholesky I have to prove that $\sum$ is hermitian. So, a positive definite matrix is always hermitian? If not, can I apply Cholesky decomposition to not-hermitian matrices?

Comment: It's symmetric with real entries (I presume), therefore it's Hermitian because $\overline{a_{ij}}=a_{ij}$.

Comment: @Gae.S. You presume?

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of a real-valued random vector, then $\Sigma$ is real and symmetric. If it is the covariance matrix of a complex-valued random vector, then $\Sigma$ is complex and hermitian. These facts follow immediately from the definition of covariance. Positive definiteness also follows immediately from the definition: $\Sigma = E[(x-\mu)(x-\mu)^*]$ (where $*$ denotes conjugate transpose). So for any $y$, we have $y^* \Sigma y = y^*E[(x-\mu)(x-\mu)^*]y = E[y^*(x-\mu)(x-\mu^*)y] = \|E[y^*(x-\mu)]\|^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: @Gianni I don't know the convention you are using.

Comment: @Bungo So if $\sum$ is symmetric with real entries we can always decompose it with Cholesky. If $\sum$ has complex entries we can decompose it only if it's hermitian. Right?

Comment: @Gianni If $\Sigma$ has real entries, then it's symmetric, by definition of the covariance matrix. If $\Sigma$ has complex entries, then it's hermitian, again by definition. In the complex case, the $i,j$'th entry of the matrix is $E[(x_i - \mu_i)\overline{(x_j - \mu_j)}]$, and the $j,i$'th entry is $E[(x_j - \mu_j)\overline{(x_i - \mu_i)}]$, which as you can see is the complex conjugate of the $i,j$'th entry. Hence $\Sigma$ is hermitian. A similar argument for the real case shows that the $i,j$'th and $j,i$'th entries are equal, hence $\Sigma$ is symmetric.

Comment: @Bungo Now I understood. Thanks!